# Receiving "The requested operation requires elevation" when updating printer drivers

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

Today all users trying to print to a shared printer from the server are receiving a prompt to update printer driver. A UAC prompt appears and asks for Admin credentials. Once the credentials have been entered the driver begins to install, but then an error message from NtPrint.exe states that The requested operation requires elevation. Nothing seems to resolve this issue.

I suspect that logging in as the admin and updating the driver might work, but that task would be daunting with 40 computers. Is there any fix for this, so that the users can simply enter the admin credentials themselves and install the driver, or perhaps not require admin credentials to install?

Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a post [here](http://blog.pythonaro.com/2013/05/fully-disable-user-access-control-uac.html) to disable UAC through GPO. After applying this and having the users reboot they can now install the drivers needed. There are a few users getting a weird issue in which they can install without error, but the driver never gets applied, so they end up in some strange drive install loop. I believe this is due to a rogue GPO from the old IT guy, so I'll consider this issue resolved.